# ¿Como hacer múltiples condiciones con el operador ternario en javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con el siguiente problema de antemano muchas gracias.

En el siguiente código paso el valor del arreglo con indice 0 a un input text llamado txtResultado.

Mi pregunta es:

**¿Como puedo hacer una condición con el operador terciario de javascript de tal forma que mi recultado se muestre sin el signo $?**.

Así funciona correctamente pero el valor datos[0] puede tener las siguientes caracteristicas puedo tenerlo como **datos[0] = null** o **datos[0]="23.50"(Sin el signo de pesos)** o **datos[0] = '$ 43.50'**.

Gracias por su ayuda.

```js
var datos = ['$ 20.50','34.11'];

$("#txtResultado").val(datos[0]).length == null ? $("#txtResultado").val(datos[0]) : $("#txtResultado").val(datos[0].replace('$',' ').trim());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<input id="txtResultado" type="text" /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Pero si ya lograste mostrarlo sin el signo $ no entiendo tu pregunta

Comment: y cuál sería el valor del input si el arreglo tiene un nulo?

Comment: Hola @PakLeiChong si el valor del arreglo es igual a nulo mi input no mostraría ningun valor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A ver si entendí bien. De tu array puedes tener null (pero si es así no le asignas ningún valor al input), 45.66 o $46.66 y si el arreglo en la posición i **NO es nulo** entonces quisieras mostrar 45.66 si tuviera el signo $ y si no tiene $ entonces se muestra tal cual.

```
if (datos[0] != null ){
    datos[0].includes("$") ?  $("#txtResultado").val(datos[0].replace('$','')) : $("#txtResultado").val(datos[0]);
}
```

Creo que yo lo resolvería de esta forma. Espero te sea útil.